# Multiple XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I call ajax request in a loop. Around 20 of them. But few are getting aborted. How can I avoid that ?

Most of them are getting aborted.

```
function callURLAsync(url) 
{
  var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    // Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
    {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', url, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
        }
    }

    self.xmlHttpReq.send();
}

function startLogout(){

    for(var i=0;i< 20;i++){
        callURLAsync("myDummyURl");
    }

}
```

Thanks
Sailesh

Comment: Do you realize that `this` is window, so you are overriding the same variable  every time you make an Ajax call. Plus 20 calls at once to the server is a bad idea.

Comment: Agreed. However when we logout, we want to clear sessions of all applications.

Comment: And what is triggering the `startLogout`? Is it a button click or unload?

Comment: logout button click

Comment: Make sure the button is not submitting the page. After that change `var self = this;` so it is not referencing the window object or the button (whatever `this` is). Change it to `var self = {};` and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Though things are slightly better, as in out of 20 now more or less 8 are getting passed. But the rest are getting aborted.

Comment: Can we set some parameter, which will stop this abort from happening ?

Comment: I heard that in IE10 max of 8 ajax requests are allowed. Is that true? If yes, can we set some thread sleep or something , so that we trigger 5 calls and later another 5 ?

Comment: You need to figure out what is causing it to abort... Make sure you cancel the button click so the page does not navigate away. Change it so you are not using a loop, but use a queue system, or change it so you make one call to the server and it kills all the sessions.

Comment: That is 8 simultaneous requests. It queues up the http calls until the stack has a spot.

Comment: Yes. You were right. The page was getting navigated away even before all the ajax requests were processed

Answer (score 0):

Reasons for Ajax calls to get aborted:

- Form or page navigation - cancel the action that is causing navigation, you can not cancel or delay onunload
- Calling abort
- Reusing same XMLHttpRequest object

In your case it sounds like the button is navigating the page away. What you need to do is use `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` from the button click. After all the Ajax calls are done, you can use `window.location` to do the redirection.